# How to initialize Http import in public function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the below Typescript code I want to call a function which requires an import. I can initialize the import in the constructor of the class, but how can I can I do this in a public function?

```
import {Http} from "angular2/http";

export class AppComponent {

  constructor( properties.
    public http: Http
    ) {
      this.http.get(...){} //FUNCTION 1: this function works fine

      this.getAll(); //this does not work as FUNCTION 2 does not work
    }

 public getAll = function(){ //FUNCTION 2: this function does not work (cannot find name'http')
      http.get(...){} 
    }

 public otherfunction = function(){
      this.getAll(); //this does not work as FUNCTION 2 does not work
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public property is accessible via `this` (current instance) reference:

```
public getAll = function() {
  this.http.get(...); 
}
```